# Building CAS war from scratch with Maven

Tags: java, maven, war, cas

I am new to Maven but have worked with Ant for years and, most recently, pretty extensively with Gradle.

I am trying to clone & build (locally) a Maven project called Apereo (formerly Jasig) [Central Authentication Service (CAS)](https://github.com/Jasig/cas). This is a Java web app playing the role of a ticket store (similar to Kerberos) in an SSO service. Typically, to *use* CAS as your SSO server, you use the Maven Overlay Method to pull in their JARs/WARs by default, and you simply override those defaults if you want to supply your own custom files.

But this is not what I want. I want to build the CAS project locally, and make my own changes/tweaks to it. So I cloned it from GitHub and issued a `mvn war:war` inside its root "`cas/`" directory. I saw a *lot* of output, ending with:

```
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar (227 KB at 1423.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar (471 KB at 804.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [cas-server] in [D:\ih8windows\cas\target\cas-server-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [213 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\ih8windows\cas\target\cas-server-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apereo Central Authentication Service ............. FAILURE [ 11.779 s]
[INFO] Apereo CAS Core ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Generic Support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Web Application support ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Web Application ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS JDBC Support ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS LDAP Support ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Legacy Support ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS OpenId Server Support .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS RADIUS Support ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS SPNEGO/NTLM Support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Trusted User Support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS X.509 Client Certificate Support ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS OAuth Server Support ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Client Protocols Support using pac4j ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS SAML Server and Validation Support ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS JBoss Cache Integration - DEPRECATED ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Memcached Integration .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Ehcache Integration .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Restlet Integration - DEPRECATED ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS - Uber WAR - DEPRECATED ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS ClearPass Extension .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS Management Web Application ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apereo CAS REST Implementation .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.142 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-10T13:56:35-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-cli) on project cas-server: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When I go to `target/` I see a `cas-server-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`, but it is empty!

Ideally, I'd like all of its subprojects to get all bundled up inside the same artifact (JAR/WAR). But if thats not possible, then I need to build & package the `cas-server-webapp` and `cas-server-core` subprojects so I can fire them up and make changes to them locally. So I ask: if `mvn war:war` isn't the way to achieve this, then what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `mvn war:war` try running `mvn package` in the main directory. It'll allow Maven to choose apropriate packaging type for each `cas` module. The project consists of many modules and not all of them should be packaged as WARs. For instance the parent project (the one which fails) has `pom` packaging type, which mean that it doesn't build anything but rather invokes submodules.

When `mvn package` completes, you should be able to find assembled `cas-server-webapp/target/cas.war` file.

Comment: Thanks @Tomek Rekawek (+1) - any idea how I could publish that `cas.war` to my local Maven repo, and then reference it (**instead** of the standard/typical CAS located in Maven Central) in my CAS project? In other words, I have a separate Maven project, called `my-sso`, and instead of using the Maven Overlay Method with standard/typical CAS, I want to use it with my own version of CAS that you just help me build. Any ideas? The [CAS docs](http://jasig.github.io/cas/development/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html) might explain what I'm talking about here better. Thanks again!